# How do I pass nested properties in javascript object to C# class

Tags: c#, javascript-objects

I have a javascript object that I am passing to a C# class in an MCV application.  Simple properties get passed over without a problem, but if my object contains nested properties, those do not get mapped over.  They are null in my C# class.

My class looks like this:

```
public class AssessmentItemModel
{
    public int StudentTestEventID { get; set;}
    public string ClientID { get; set;}
    public int TestID { get; set;}
    public TestItemCollection ItemCollection { get; set; }
}

public class TestItemCollection
{
    [DataMember]
    public ConcurrentDictionary<int,TestItem> TestItems {get; set;}
}
```

My javascript:

```
var tmpModel = {};
    tmpModel.TestID = jsonModel.TestID;
    tmpModel.StudentTestEventID = jsonModel.StudentTestEventID;
    tmpModel.ClientID = jsonModel.ClientID;
    tmpModel.ItemCollection = {};
    tmpModel.ItemCollection.TestItems = jsonModel.ItemCollection.TestItems;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: getOTCPath() + "Assessment/FinishAssessment/",
        data: tmpModel
    });
```

The FinishAssessment method:

```
 [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult FinishAssessment(AssessmentItemModel aModel)
    {
        //string responses = aModel.TestResponses;
        //aModel = RestoreAssessmentItemModel(aModel);
        //aModel.TestResponses = responses;
        AssessmentSvcHelper helper = new AssessmentSvcHelper();
        string result = helper.FinishAssessment(aModel.StudentTestEventID.ToString(), aModel.ItemCollection, aModel.ClientID, int.Parse(aModel.TestID), aModel.FormID);
        aModel.StudentScore = result;

        return View("FinishAssessment", aModel);

    }
```

When I get to the FinishAssessment method, the AssessmentItemModel is populated with StudentTestEventID, ClientID and TestID correctly.  It also has a value for ItemCollection but the TestItems property under ItemCollection is null.

From the reading I've done it appears that nested or complex properties don't get mapped over.

How do I get the entire object passed over to my class?

Comment: Have you tried defining your TestItems as just a List<TestItem> and see if it works? If it does and it's important to you to have a ConcurrentDictionary, you could easily convert the List<TestItem> using something like this: TestItems.Distinct().ToDictionary(t => t.TestId, t => t);

Comment: I agree with @Thierry but also, your dictionary is of `<int, TestItem>`. It looks like you are setting the key to a string, `TestItems`, not an `int`, from the javascript. Have you tried `tmpModel.ItemCollection["1"] = jsonModel.ItemCollection.TestItems;`?

Comment: I'm not sure if ConcurrentDictonary is needed or not but don't know what impacts it would have on the rest of the system if it's changed so for now I'm going to assume it needs to stay that way.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not nested properties but that you are using Dictionary which is not supported by default by model binder (unless you build a custom one).

Changing this

```
public ConcurrentDictionary<int,TestItem> TestItems {get; set;} //do you need concurrent??
```

by this

```
public List<TestItem> TestItems {get; set;}
```

would accept submitting this JSON structure

```
tempModel = {
    ..props..
    ItemCollection = [
        { testItemProp1, testItemProp2 ..} //don't know this structure
    ]
};
```

I drop the index I suppose you have in your collection as you have defined your dictionary as `Dictionary<int,TestItem>`, don't know if you need it, but JSON structure should match your class definition. Only think you need is to use some IEnumerable<> for the model binder to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem some years ago and used `JSON.stringify(myObject)` and then returned the stringified object in the AJAX call; I then used

```
JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<myTargetObject>(myObject)
```

in the controller

Comment: I am trying this approach now but getting an error.   var deserializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var result = deserializer.Deserialize<List<TestItem>>(aModel.ItemCollection);

The error is "Argument type 'TestItemCollection' is not assignable to parameter type string.

Comment: You need to deserialise the return object in full - `var result = deserializer.Deserialize<List<TestItem>>(aModel)`